# Getting Back NULL from Javascript Regular Expressions in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

The following code is part of a Node.js application. Am trying to use regular expressions to get the url parts, but with difficulty. When it is passed an obviously matching 'req.url' string, where even regex.test(req.url) returns true, am getting back null from regex.match. Why so? When I use regex.match() without using regex.test() in front, I get the regex results array OK... But I need to do a regex.test() in the real application. And isn't it possible/legal to use regex.match() right after regex.test()?

For instance, when `req.url = "/?format=html&path=/news/crawl/2015/10/01/http---newssite.com--crawl.html"` I get a null from regex.match. In fact no string ever matches with the following code:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        if (req.method == 'GET') {
            var readRegex = /\?format=(json|html|txt)&path=([\w.\/_-]+)/g;
            var file_path, regex_results;
            console.log(req.url);
            switch (true) {
                case readRegex.test(req.url):
                    regex_results = readRegex.exec(req.url);
                    if (regex_results !== null) {
                        console.log(regex_results);                        
                    } else {
                        console.log("Error: 'regex_results' is null!");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            res.writeHead(503, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.end("{'error':'Method not yet implemented!'}");
        }
    }).listen(22000, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: Either your test string or your regexp is wrong as that regexp [*does match*](https://regex101.com/r/zD9qO6/1) that test string. It also returns non-null when used with `.exec()`.

Comment: Still my begging question remains...

Why doesn't a consecutive regex.test and/or regex.match not work... one will match while the other will fail, no matter the ordering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason `regexp.exec()` fails after calling `regexp.test()` is because `regexp.test()` sets the `regexp.lastIndex` to the end of the string, which is where the last match ended.

So when `regexp.exec()` executes, it tries to start off at `regexp.lastIndex` (the end of the string), which never matches anything because it's the same string.

You can reset this property manually after `regexp.test()` via `regexp.lastIndex = 0;`.

Comment: Just wanted to write that. :)

Comment: Or just remove the `g` option from the regex expression.

Comment: This was the answer I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll try without the /g option also. Thank you!